# What is the total numbers of $watch an AngularJS application can have?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

What is the total numbers of $watch an AngularJS can have? Is there any performance issue of the application depends on this numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A large number of AngularJS watchers are usually the source of slowdowns in angular build applications.

When using `$scope.$watch(...)` angular will create a new watcher to check for changes on each `$digest cycle` and be able to notify the controller or update the view.

It is generally accepted that once the number of watchers reaches 2000+, an application will start to suffer.

Answer (score 1):

It can not be said that there is a "limit" on the number of watchers on a page.

However, watchers do have a cost in terms of performance. You should **avoid creating them when this can be avoided**: reducing the number of watchers will directly improve the [digest cycle](https://www.thinkful.com/projects/understanding-the-digest-cycle-528/)’s performance.

---

I invit you to read [**this very interesting paper**](https://www.airpair.com/angularjs/posts/angularjs-performance-large-applications) about AngularJS performance and watchers.